# AWS uploading file into wrong bucket

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

I am using AWS Sagemaker and trying to upload a data folder into S3 from Sagemaker. I am trying to do is to upload my data into the s3_train_data directory (the directory exists in S3). However, it wouldn't upload it in that bucket, but in a default Bucket that has been created, and in turn creates a new folder directory with the S3_train_data variables.

code to input in directory

```
import os
import sagemaker
from sagemaker import get_execution_role

sagemaker_session = sagemaker.Session()
role = get_execution_role()

bucket = <bucket name>
prefix = <folders1/folders2>
key = <input>


s3_train_data = 's3://{}/{}/{}/'.format(bucket, prefix, key)


#path 'data' is the folder in the Jupyter Instance, contains all the training data
inputs = sagemaker_session.upload_data(path= 'data', key_prefix= s3_train_data)
```

Is the problem in the code or more in how I created the notebook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could look at the Sample notebooks, how to upload the data S3 bucket 
There have many ways. I am just giving you hints to answer. 
And you forgot create a boto3 session to access the S3 bucket

**It is one of the ways to do it.**

```
import os 
import urllib.request
import boto3

def download(url):
    filename = url.split("/")[-1]
    if not os.path.exists(filename):
        urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, filename)


def upload_to_s3(channel, file):
    s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
    data = open(file, "rb")
    key = channel + '/' + file
    s3.Bucket(bucket).put_object(Key=key, Body=data)


# caltech-256
download('http://data.mxnet.io/data/caltech-256/caltech-256-60-train.rec')
upload_to_s3('train', 'caltech-256-60-train.rec')
download('http://data.mxnet.io/data/caltech-256/caltech-256-60-val.rec')
upload_to_s3('validation', 'caltech-256-60-val.rec')
```

link : https://buildcustom.notebook.us-east-2.sagemaker.aws/notebooks/sample-notebooks/introduction_to_amazon_algorithms/imageclassification_caltech/Image-classification-fulltraining.ipynb

**Another way to do it.**

```
bucket = '<your_s3_bucket_name_here>'# enter your s3 bucket where you will copy data and model artifacts
prefix = 'sagemaker/breast_cancer_prediction' # place to upload training files within the bucket
# do some processing then prepare to push the data. 

f = io.BytesIO()
smac.write_numpy_to_dense_tensor(f, train_X.astype('float32'), train_y.astype('float32'))
f.seek(0)

boto3.Session().resource('s3').Bucket(bucket).Object(os.path.join(prefix, 'train', train_file)).upload_fileobj(f)
```

Link : https://buildcustom.notebook.us-east-2.sagemaker.aws/notebooks/sample-notebooks/introduction_to_applying_machine_learning/breast_cancer_prediction/Breast%20Cancer%20Prediction.ipynb

Youtube link : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-YiHPIGyFGo - how to pull the data in S3 bucket.